# Blank space on top of the page (sometimes)

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

There is a problem on my website that I can't resolve. Sometimes there is a blank space on top, between the header/navigation and the content. After reloading the page it disappears.

This happens an desktop and mobile devices.

My website is www.timschuermann.com/dev/

Comment: By blank space do you mean white-space? So ideally there shouldn't be any space between the navbar and the picture?

Comment: You only provide a link to the site where you are having problem. Imagine what the next guy will find when he is looking for help with a similar problem. What if your site has changed or is taken down? Thus, when you ask a question on SO, always include relevant code. (You can edit it in!)

Comment: As for a solution to the problem (which I cannot reproduce), check if it has to do with the wordpress admin bar by testing it when logged out. So start a clean session browser window (ctrl-shift-N in chrome), visit your site and see if you still have a problem. (If you now have no problem, then at least it's only an issue for logged in users.) This might be relevant: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-the-28px-push-down-from-the-admin-bar/ (I searched for `wordpress admin-bar margin` and picked the first hit)

Answer (score 0):

In your css try setting body margin and padding to 0

`body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}`